# Returning Plot Color

Tags: pine-script

I have an indicator that changes the color of the line plot based on calculated conditions. Is there a way to return the plot color in Pine Script? I can use the formula outside the function to return the color, but I am interested in the plot value as it is represented on the screen which includes the displacement value.

Thank you.
A.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly return the plot colour from the plot function. You will have to derive it from the conditions and variables used to determine it in the first place including any offset/displacement.

Comment: How do you adjust the values to reflect the displacement on the graph? Is there a multiplier or something to use?  I used the displacement value but it seems that it's not 1:1.